# How to change the data format to one column and export as csv in Python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, database, numpy

The picture is just an example and I hope to change this data(str type) to one column (float type) and save as csv in Python. Pandas or Numpy may help but I don't know how to do that. Could someone help me please? Thank you very much.

[data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ62m.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert as float, you just need to use `astype` method in your dataframe, and to save it as csv you just need to use `to_csv` method for your dataframe.

Here's the example of your case:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"String_type":["2.1","4","5.2"]})

# convert string to float
df["float_type"] = df["String_type"].astype(float)

# save as csv, change out.csv to your filename
df.to_csv('out.csv')

print(df.dtypes)
```

Hope this would be helpful.